# How to detect newlines (return) from a multiline string text in TextEditor SwiftUI?

Tags: macos, swiftui

How would you take a multiline string input into `TextEditor` in SwiftUI and detect the breaks (newlines)?

edit: "detect the breaks" here refers to when a user presses the return button on a keyboard.

Comment: What do you mean "detect"? You want to know if the content has `\n` in it? Or you want to get an "event" of some sort when the user enters that into the `TextEditor`? Or something else?

Comment: Do you want the same event if the user presses `return` in the middle of the content compared to the end? What if they paste in text that has `\n` in it -- do you want an event then?

Comment: I would like to detect the same event even if the user presses `return` in the middle of the content. As for pasting `\n` I would want to ignore that. Though didn't think of that case hah.

Comment: Don't have time to write out a full answer at the moment, but my suggestion would be to use `onChange` -- compare the new value to the old value. If it's just one character different (eg not pasted) and that character is a `\n`, there's your event. Another option would be to listen to the `FocusState` and then set up a separate key listener (may have to drop down to AppKit to make one that doesn't block key entry) and just listen for the return key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnChange` detects each time a value is entered and clears the last when it is newline. Is this the right implementation?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $text)
                .onChange(of: text) { newValue in
                    print(newValue)
                    if newValue.contains("\n") {
                        text = String(text.dropLast())
                    }
                }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This will do! Simple is best, thanks.